# I am trying to decompose the HTML part of the code by using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Here is the input HTML snippet:

```
<p>both before<img src="it is free"style="width:590px;height:228px;"> and after img tag</p>
```

Here is the desired output snippet:

```
<p> both before </p><img src="it is free"style="width:590px;height:228px;"><p>after img tag</p>
```

Here is my code snippet:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import NavigableString
while len(p_tag.contents) != 0: 
    item = p_tag.contents.pop(0)
    if isinstance(item, NavigableString):
        new_tag = doc.new_tag('p')
        new_tag.string = item
        current_tag.insert_after(new_tag)
        current_tag = current_tag.next_sibling
    else:
        new_tag = item
        current_tag.insert_after(new_tag)
        current_tag = current_tag.next_sibling
```

But I am getting the following error, although I am pretty sure that I have tag content:

```
     raise ValueError("Tag.index: element not in tag")
     ValueError: Tag.index: element not in tag
```

Please use 'html5lib' as a parser for BeautifulSoup ex:

```
doc = BeautifulSoup(open(input_doc), 'html5lib')
```

Is there any way to get out of this error?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working version of the code:

```
p_tag_contents = p_tag.contents
current = p_tag
for i in range(len(p_tag_contents)):
    item = copy.copy(p_tag_contents[i])
    if isinstance(item, NavigableString):
        new_element = doc.new_tag('p')
        new_element.string = item
        current.insert_after(new_element)
        current = current.next_sibling
    else:
        current.insert_after(item)
        current = current.next_sibling
p_tag.decompose()
```

What we need to do is first get the all contents of a given tag and then insert them after the given tag and finally destroy the given tag. The reason why I use copy in here is that without copying the contents `len(p_tag.contents)` changes in each iteration which causes programming error.